# Connection refused while querying a web server which runs on an ephemeral port

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I want to run a web server on an ephemeral port and somehow keep the knowledge of its number. I decided to do it in such a way:

```
from flask import Flask

import socket

app = Flask(__name__)

def find_free_port():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 0))
    port = sock.getsockname()[1]
    sock.close()
    return port

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=find_free_port())
```

On my personal computer I can query both `localhost` and `0.0.0.0` but there is a machine where it does not work, I receive

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:<port_number>; Connection refused
```

What might be the cause? The problem disappears when I use `localhost` as the interface instead of binding to all of them

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use the real IP address lets say `192.168.1.104` on the other machine, it will work.

This is because when you use `0.0.0.0` on the other machine, you will be requesting from the same machine yet the port is not open.

so change the request to `http://ip_address:port_number`